# How to extrude random individual faces

Tags: modeling

Is there a method to extrude faces randomly to get uneven height of the extruded mesh?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe you could extrude it in the same height, put all those vertices in the vertex group and use displace texture on only those vertices in the group... But to randomly extrude? I don't think that there is a default way to do it, maybe with help of proportional editing, ..... hmm I just tried it, and no, my thought is not possible to achieve, so maybe there is some other way

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a few steps but I found a way do do this.

`I` Select all the faces you want to extrude and extrude them with no movement. You can also instead use an inset with size 0 if you want your edges to separate the heights.

(if your faces are not aligned with a global or local axis, now would be the time to create a custom axis by clicking the little + in the transform orientations dropdown)

`II` Use the Mesh>Transform>Randomize Operator with an Amount of your choosing, Uniform set to 0 and Normal set to 1.

`III` Set your Pivot Point to Individual Origins and scale along the relevant Axis by 0 (the one normal to your faces)

It's done

Answer (score 5):

A work around could be:

-Extrude the individual faces that you want <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> > Extrude individual faces

-Then solo those faces <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> and deselect all after that.

-Go to Select > Select Random

-Move the faces <kbd>G</kbd> + (any axis) a bit and finally unhide everything <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What got me what I wanted was enabling the Add-on [Mesh: Edit Mesh Tools](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/edit_mesh_tools.html) from the preferences and using "Multi Extrude".

Comment: Good tip, thanks for the information, always glad someone can share more techniques!